# Unmarshal JSON into struct with multiple embedded structs and overlapping fields names

Tags: json, go, data-structures, unmarshalling

I'm trying to parse an API response where response can be of two different types.

In API's JSON schema this response is defined like this ():

```
"account_user_settings": {
      "type": "object",
      "allOf": [
        {
          "$ref": "objects.json#/definitions/users_user_min"
        },
        {
          "$ref": "objects.json#/definitions/users_user_settings_xtr"
        }
      ]
    }
```

So I defined several types:

```
type AccountUserSettings struct {
    UsersUserMin
    UsersUserSettingsXtr
}

type UsersUserMin struct {
    FirstName       string `json:"first_name"`
    Id              int    `json:"id"`
    LastName        string `json:"last_name"`
}

type UsersUserSettingsXtr struct {
    Bdate            string  `json:"bdate"`
    City             string  `json:"city"`
    Country          string  `json:"country"`
    FirstName        string  `json:"first_name"`
    LastName         string  `json:"last_name"`
    Phone            string  `json:"phone"`
}
```

Response contains JSON similar to this (only values were changed):

First possible option (full):

```
{
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "bdate": "9.3.1950",
    "city": "New York",
    "country": "USA",
    "phone": "+1 234 567 8910",
}
```

Second option (partial):

```
{
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "id": 123
}
```

The problem is that with this configuration I always miss values for fields `FirstName` and `LastName` after unmarshaling.

If I exclude on of the embedded types from consolidating type (`AccountUserSettings`) then it works fine and all fields are properly filled.

I have only one option for now how to resolve this, and don't think it's good enough - don't use embedding and enlist all fields directly in `AccountUserSettings`.

Maybe there are any other options you know for similar cases?

Comment: The option you mention, is a good option. Do you have any specific reason why you believe it is not good enough?

Comment: ... an alternative to that, although personally I don't think it's a good option, would be to check the bytes for a string that can be present only in one response type but not the other and based on the result of that check allocate the correct struct and unmarshal into that. For example you could check if the json contains the string `"id":` and if you're certain that xtr json would never contain that string, not as a property and not as a value, then you know that you can unmarshal the json into the min struct.

Comment: Another option would be embedding a third type with the `FirstName` and `LastName` fields, and removing those fields from both other types. But I agree with mkopriva - I would just put all the fields directly in the one struct unless there's some good reason not to.

Comment: Thank you guys for all the ideas.Those two types (`UsersUserMin` and `UsersUserSettingsXtr`) are used in other part of the code. So I just wanted to reuse it to avoid code duplication. But it seems the best option will be to directly define all fields in the type.